# htaccess rewrite rule for domain alias with single subdir

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a large .htaccess file for my site to control alias names and subdirectories

e.g. mysite/townname is set to load specific content as follows (vbulletin) - 2 entries for handling whether ends in / or not that works ok

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ content.php?r=157&town=$1&newtownidmethod=1&showregion=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ content.php?r=157&town=$1&newtownidmethod=1&showregion=1 [NC]
```

The above works ok for mainsite/subdir1 and doesn't invoke if mainsite/subdir1/subdir2

But if certain alias domain is being used I want to load a different content e.g. content.php?r=9, but only if a subdir1 only. The subdir1 is actually town names and there are 650 of them.

Real example

- `www.qlocal.co.uk/southport` will load content.php=157 for a home page with news (content.php=157) as in above rewriterule's
- `www.movingdiy.co.uk/southport` - I want to load a different home page with property for sale  (content.php=9)

I need to detect (rewritecond I assume) that using site movingdiy.co.uk AND if only one (and only one) subdir specified in the url then load different content.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?movingdiy\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ content.php?r=157&town=$1&newtownidmethod=1&showregion=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?movingdiy\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ content.php?r=9&town=$1&newtownidmethod=1&showregion=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work ok. I have a few other alias domains that use the same site but all with the content.php?r=157. Am I correct in IF I PUT the second condition first it will then work or would I have to put in a condition for each alias domain. What I suggest does seem to work but using.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?movingdiy\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ content.php?r=9&town=$1&newtownidmethod=1&showregion=1 [L,QSA]

The other domains seem to still work ok like www.qlocal.co.uk/southport and www.southport.gb.com/southport.

Thanks again, off to do testing

Comment: ok check updated answer now. First one uses negation now which means all sites other than `www.movingdiy.co.uk/` will have `?r=157`.